# VSCode shorcut to tab between files on secondary editor group

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, keymapping, keymaps

I'm currently using VSCode to edit latex documents. The setup I have is the latex document in one editor group to the left, and then the preview of the document (pdf) in another group to the right. Additionally, I keep some other files open in the right work group as well.

Is there a way to make a shortcut, which tabs through the files in right work group, while the focus remains on the left one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any built-in way to do that. You can use a macro to do it though pretty easily.  Using a macro extension like [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) put this into your settings:

```
"multiCommand.commands": [

 {
  "command": "multiCommand.NextEditorOtherGroup",
  "sequence": [
    "workbench.action.focusNextGroup",
    "workbench.action.nextEditorInGroup",
    "workbench.action.focusNextGroup"
    //  "workbench.action.focusPreviousGroup" if you more than two editor groups for example
  ]
 },
{
  "command": "multiCommand.PreviousEditorOtherGroup",
  "sequence": [
    "workbench.action.focusNextGroup",
    "workbench.action.previousEditorInGroup",
    "workbench.action.focusNextGroup"
  ]
 }
]
```

The macro just focuses the other editor group (it assumes you only have two, if you have more the macro could be modified to focus the `right/last/most recently used` editor group as well.  After focusing the other editor group it moves to the next/previous editor in that other group and then returns focus to the other group (since you only have two editor groups `focusNextGroup` works perfectly fine here, if you had more and wanted to return to the previously focussed group use `workbench.action.focusPreviousGroup` instead).

and then whatever keybindings you want to use to trigger those macros (in keybindings.json):

```
{
  "key": "alt+q",              // trigger the macro with any keybinding you wish
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": { "command": "multiCommand.NextEditorOtherGroup" },
  "when": "editorTextFocus"
},
{
  "key": "shift+alt+q",        // any keybinding
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": { "command": "multiCommand.PreviousEditorOtherGroup" },
  "when": "editorTextFocus"
},
```